# Azure devops Octopus deploy release name semver check

Tags: azure, azure-devops, octopus-deploy

We are using Azure Devops with Octopus deploy.
I have integrated the release steps, and release creation as well as release to first environment (Development in my case) is happening without any issue.

Issue is with subsequent releases.
Release fails in Semantic Versioning check of release name.

> '1.2.1023.0508-09' is not a valid version string
>
> at Octopus.Client.Model.SemanticVersion.Parse(String value, Boolean
> preserveMissingComponents)

In the first stage, I am creating Octopus release, and deploying to Development environment in the same task (using Create Octopus Release task in Azure devops)

```
create-release "--project=<projectName>" "--releaseNumber=1.2.1023.0508-09" "--server=<serverName>" "--apiKey=***" --enableServiceMessages "--deployTo=Development" --progress "--releaseNotesFile=<path>"
```

This step is successful.
In the next stage, I have tried 2 variations,

- Promote Release

> promote-release "--project=projectName" "--server=serverName"
> "--apiKey=***" "--from=Development" "--to=envName"

- Deploy Release

> deploy-release "--project=projectName" "--releaseNumber=latest"
> "--server=serverName" "--apiKey=***" "--deployTo=envName"

Both of them giving same error, saying release name is not a valid version string.

My confusion is, if the name is incorrect, even the first deployment should fail.
If it's correct and allowed, then subsequent stage release should also succeed.

If any one has faced such a issue before, or can add in some pointers to resolve this issue, it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case if someone came here looking for solution, below are the steps I took to solve the problem,

- For first stage (dev in my case), create a new release. If you have multiple tenants, add them. Do not forget to add Package Version. This is especially needed when you have multiple versions of artifacts getting created. I faced hard time resolving this. if you do not add PackageVersion, latest available artifact is picked.
- For further stages, DO NOT promote release. Instead, deploy release. This way, you can pass the same release number as configured in first stage. In my case, I kept the stage name same as my environment name. So I was able to use variable for env as well. I copied this stage for 4 different environments.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug but I'd need more time to reproduce and verify. Can you share what version of Octopus and the Octopus Extension you are using?

My best suggestion to get going with this is to base the release number off of your Azure DevOps build number and use that variable to control what version is getting deployed. Using the 'latest' version could backfire if you have other releases created in between your stages.

If you can set your Azure DevOps build number to be in the same format that you want your Octopus release number (1.2.1023.0508-09), you can use the following commands to build and promote a release.

```
create-release "--project=<projectName>" "--releaseNumber=$(Build.BuildNumber)" "--server=<serverName>" "--apiKey=***" --enableServiceMessages "--deployTo=Development" --progress "--releaseNotesFile=<path>"

deploy-release "--project=projectName" "--releaseNumber=$(Build.BuildNumber)" "--server=serverName" "--apiKey=***" "--deployTo=envName"
```

This will make sure that you are promoting the same release that was created in the pipeline.

Comment: Using version 2018.9.11
With your suggestion to use buildNumber, I was able to go ahead and release.

- Deploy Release passed.

- Promote Release failed.

But the problem with that is, in case you want to create another release on same build, Octopus gives out error. As release already exists with same name. So user will need to trigger build again. 

For the very reason I had kept releaseName as Octopus release name. 

Your suggestion solves the problem partially, not completely. Hence not marking as answer.

Comment: Oh, you shouldn't hard code the build number to a static value. It should be a dynamic for each AzureDevOps build.

Unless you mean that you are creating more than one Octopus release in the same project in an Azure DevOps build. If so, what is the use case for that?

Comment: not hard coding. Instead of build number, I am using azure release name as Octopus release id. That ways, in case of some failure or any release variable update, even if i create a new release on same build, octopus release will have new id. And it will not give error of release already exists.